# How to restrict the display of text while showing to client and later it should be shown after clicking the show more button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need to display only certain part of the text and remaining shoud be showed only after clicking "show more" button I am using java script as controller  and angular js as front end

Comment: Show us your `HTML` or any effort.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-hide or ng-show

[Hiding HTML Elements-W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp)

Comment: I know that but it is not performing in my requirement